# Access protected members from a public derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope, pass-by-reference

I am getting an error when trying to access a protected member of a base  class from a method of a derived class which inherits public.

I am passing by reference two objects of the base class to the method of the derived class and try to access the objects' protected member. However, the editor complains.

In sort, here is what I am trying to do:

```
class A {
protected:
  int x;
};

class B:public A
{
public:
  void test(A &obj1, A &obj2)
  {
    obj1.x = 1;
    obj2.x = 2;
  }
};
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQtDX.png) is the complain from the editor:

```
 int A::x
 protected member A::x (declared at line 5) is not accessible though "A" pointer or object.
```

What is wrong with my code and what can I do to correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please copy and paste error messages, don't use external links or images for them.  If you attempt to compile, the compiler will likely give you the same message, which would be easier to copy from.

Comment: Apparently, I can not upload an image yet since I do not have enough badges. Instead a link was created automatically with the error written.

Comment: You can access `x` by a `B` object, but not by an `A` object.

Comment: The access modifier Protected means that the member variable x is accessible by methods inside of class A not Class B and thus cannot be accessed through Class B.

Answer (score 1):

You can only access base class protected members of classes with the same type as the derived object. You will have to make a public method to obtain the member or other workaround. Imagine you had another class C, which inherited A as private. You could pass C to the B method as an A reference, but the base class members wouldn't be accessible. If the references passed to the B method where B references, then you would be able to access the protected members in them.

Comment: Access does not need to be through `this` specifically, but it does need to be through an object of the derived type.

Answer (score 0):

For class A the variable x is protected which will act like private for class A, so the member variable A::X is not accessible.

However, if you change the method

```
void test(A &obj1, A &obj2)
```

to

```
void test(B &obj1, B &obj2)
```

Then you can access the variable x from class B, as its available as protected as inheritance is public.

So, the whole code can be written like follows for accessing x in class B:

```
class A {
    protected:
        int x;
};

class B:public A
{
    public:
        void test(B &obj1, B &obj2)
        {
            obj1.x = 1;
            obj2.x = 2;
        }
};
```